# hacer un secuencia de números y advertir que ya existe esa secuencia en textboxes

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es introducir en 40 apartados tres números del 0 al 99, uno en cada textbox separadas, para comparar esa secuencia con otros textbox del mismo formato, es decir,  no se puede repetir la secuencia, no importando donde se empiece a introducir los números.

Comment: no evaluaste crear un User Control ? con un control propio podrias poner los 3 textbox pero en el form usarias tu propio control

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! MAs alla de user control o no, cual seria el problema en si?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Yo personalmente no entiendo cual es el problema que tienes. Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y explicar un poco mejor cual es exactamente tu problema?

Answer (score 1):

No uses diferentes `TextBox`, usa un solo [`MaskedTextBox`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox?view=netframework-4.7.2) al que le pondrías una máscara. Por ejemplo para tres números separados por punto la máscara sería:

```
maskedTextBox.Mask = "###.###.###";
```

Ten en cuenta que después, el valor te lo devolverá con la máscara (por ejemplo `"123.456.789"`).

Comment: Usted respondiendo preguntas de c#? O.o

Comment: La etiqueta [tag:c++] está muy inactiva ú_ù

Answer (score 0):

Podrias crear un `User Control` que permita componer los 3 textbox en uno

[User Control in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7d3362/user-control-in-C-Sharp/)

puedes crear un proyecto separado como libreria o podrias directo el control en el propio proyecto winform que tienes, en ambos casos vas a poder arrastrar el control desde la toolbox al form

```
public partial class SerialNumber : UserControl
{

   //resto codigo

   public string SerialNumber
   {
       get{return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", TextBox1.Text,TextBox2.Text,TextBox3.Text); }
   }
}
```

La idea es que dentro del control definas los 3 textbox para que despues el control exponga la propiedad que retorna el numero de serie como un sola cadena